# displaying list of registered user in django-admin

Tags: django, django-admin

My `Book` model has an `author` attribute which today is simply a CharField. The value for `author` should be one of the registered users of my Django site. When creating a new `Book` object in Django admin, I would like `author` to be displayed as a combo box showing all registered users. How would I go about achieving this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make your `author` attribute a foreign key to `django.contrib.auth.models.User` and use [limit_choices_to](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey).

Comment: if you're linking to auth.models.User you don't really need to limit the choices - if they're registered users, they're in contrib.auth's User table